# Append "[Answered]" to question's TITLE tag--for search engines

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer

Proposal: When an answer is accepted by the OP, the question's webpage will get "[Answered]" appended to its title tag.

Why: Many who come to Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange-family sites, get here from search engines. We all know what it's like, wasting time looking through webpages that have questions... but not answers.

It would be IMMEDIATELY ATTRACTIVE, to search engine users looking for answers, if they could see *right on their search results*, that the Stack Overflow webpage in their search results was an *answered* question. They would then sometimes choose the Stack Overflow-"answered" question first, over the other, ambiguous answers in their search results.

Also, obviously, it would save time, for anyone coming here from off-site.

I realize that if you're already on the site, you can tell what's answered, but we want to attract those that are *not* on the site already, (and serve them effectively).

(Honestly, where I got this idea: I was googling re' a Firefox question, and my search results included a site that put "[SOLVED]", at the beginning of their title tag... and guess where I went?)

So:  outreach, and effective service.

---

I meant that this would happen AUTOMATICALLY, once the OP accepts an answer.

I like a variation proposed by l4mpi, of showing the number of answers... but as I initially suggested, none of that would show unless the OP marked an answer as accepted.

Please do not downrate this question, for objections to things that I did NOT propose, such as "any answer, accepted or not". The point is not to ***"perfectly predict"*** whether the answer helps the search engine user. The point is to ***"statistically improve"***, or speed up, their search.

Comment: what about questions that are answered with multiple up votes where the user has never accepted the answer? the answer would more than likely still be useful.

Comment: @Tanner, you have a point. How about putting [Answered] in case the question has at least 2 (or some treshold number) answers, and [Accepted] in case there is an accepted answer. Or maybe just put [Answered] if there are answers, as acceptance of a reliable criterion.

Comment: You cannot reliably know if a question has received an answer which solves the problem of the googler, no matter if the answer is accepted or not. You could in theory include the _number_ of answers to show if a question has received answers or not, but even that might have false positives, e.g. the question containing something like "I tried foo and bar but they don't work in my special case" where foo or bar solve the googlers problem, or in case of dupes. All in all, I don't see your proposal improving search results.

Comment: See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/248731 - this would presumably be a network-wide change, not just SO.

Comment: On a different note, regarding the latest addition in your edit, from [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) topic,  `On posts tagged "feature-request", voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.`

Comment: @jonrsharpe:  Thanks for the link.  Sure, makes sense to me, for all sites.  However, I would prefer "[Answered]", over "[Solved]", for reasons that SouravGhosh has covered:  It may or may not be a solution for the searcher.  However, it saves me & others time, to know which questions have ***not*** been answered.

Answer (score 4):

Here lies two issues.

1. **Who should be entitled to put that [SOLVED] / [ANSWERED]/ [FIXED] in the title?**

   1.1. ***Automatic Addition*** : Based on what criterion / criteria? *Accepted?* What if is the accepted answer is wrong (rare but not impossible)? See My second point for related details.

   1.2. ***Manual Addition:*** Who should be entitled to put that [SOLVED] / [ANSWERED]/ [FIXED] in the title? *OP? MODs? DIAMONDs? Trusted users? Gold badge holders?* A big, big argument follows.
2. **What if a question with a poor quality asnwer is marked [SOLVED] and a better one (not exact dupe, however) has an infinitely better answer but lacks the acceptance mark from OP?**

   *You'll have a high probability to deprive someone of a better answer, isn't it?*

<sup>MY personal opinions.</sup>

Comment: OP is not talking about editing the title, but to automatically present a different title to search engine robots, if the question has received an answer (or maybe only if the answer was accepted). Thus both of your points are somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @l4mpi Isee. Thanks. Will update my answer accrodingly.

Comment: Sourav, I'm curious when "high probability" arose, in your argument?  You acknowledge that accepted answers being wrong is "rare, but not impossible".  Re' dups:  we have mechanisms to prevent them, and other users & moderators usually add links to the dup.  I usually click links to duplicates (don't you?). I usually look at other answers (I'll bet you do, too), and the highest rated answer is moved up.  Also, please notice that you have objections to things I did not propose:  I was proposing only doing this automatically, once the OP has accepted one, as solving the problem.

Comment: @Doug_Ivison egh, bad formatting. Hope it's clear now. I was trying to make the point that `in case "[SOLVED]" is used to find the best possible solutions, then` --> read point (2) now.

Comment: Re' point number 2:  I realize that this feature would not help, when the OP has not marked something as accepted.  OPs not following up and accepting is unfortunate... but as I said above, the question is not does this help *all* the situations that could be helped;  the question is:  when it happens, is it helpful?